# Mixin multiple classes at once in Python?

Tags: python, mixins

Does anyone know how I might get the following piece of code to work?

```
def mixin(TargetClass, *args, **kwargs):
    """*args is a bunch of classes to mixin to the TargetClass"""
    if kwargs.get('name') is None:
        kwargs['name'] = '%s_mixed_with_%s' % (TargetClass.__name__, "".join(map(str, args)))

    class MixedClass(TargetClass, *args):
        pass

    MixedClass.__name__ = kwargs.get('name')
    return MixedClass

# assume for all intents and purposes that Foo, Bar, Baz, Bot, Quux, and Muck are Classes
# Foo should inherit from all of Bar, Baz, Bot, Quux, and Muck
def uber_foo = mixin(Foo, Bar, Baz, Bot, Quux, Muck, name="UberFoo")`
```

Right now the Python interpreter (2.7.5) raises the following error:

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Comment: Do some of your `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz`, etc. types have metaclasses? (You can find out by inspecting `type(Foo)` and looking for anything that's not `type`.) If the set of mixins has more than one distinct metaclass, you'll get a error about the conflict, just like the one you describe. You could try to make a combined metaclass, but I'd fear that it won't work correctly (many metaclasses do deep magic, and they're not likely to be coded with collaborative multiple inheritance in mind).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about:

```
return type(kwargs.get('name'),(TargetClass,)+args,{})
```

instead of:

```
class MixedClass(TargetClass, *args):
    pass

MixedClass.__name__ = kwargs.get('name')
return MixedClass
```

And of course, the last line of your script is probably raising a `SyntaxError` as `def whatever = something` is invalid.  That should probably be:

```
UberFoo = mixin(Foo,Bar,Baz,Bot,Quux,Muck,name='UberFoo')
```

Comment: My second thought. My first one was why not just create a `class AllMixedIn(Foo, Bar, Baz, Bot, Quux, Muck): pass` and then do `class SomeName(AllMixedIn)`... but +1 from me

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks! Also my bad about the def ... = - I make that mistake all the time in Python since I do a lot of programming in Groovy as well where def is used before function, method and var declarations.